# Ignore Null when summing elements of a list, but return Null if all elements are Null

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

Let's say I have two different lists for which I want to compute the total

```
list1 = {1, Null, 2, Null}
list2 = {Null, Null, Null, Null}
```

For list1, I want the total to be 3, i.e. ignore the Null elements and add the numeric ones. For list2, I want the total to be a Null since all elements are Null. I achieve want I want for list1 with

```
In[255]:= Total[DeleteCases[list1, Null]]

Out[255]= 3
```

However, the same command applied to list2 returns 0

```
In[254]:= Total[DeleteCases[list2, Null]]

Out[254]= 0
```

On the other hand, using only Total does not work with list1

```
In[256]:= Total[list1]

Out[256]= 3 + 2 Null
```

but works for list 2

```
In[257]:= Total[list2]

Out[257]= 4 Null
```

I'd like a command that works for both lists because the list might look like list1 or list2 depending on a parametrization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Total@list1 /. {Plus[x_, Times[_, Null]] -> x}  (* 3 *)
Total@list2 /. {Plus[x_, Times[_, Null]] -> x}  (* 4 Null *)
```

Comment: Thanks! nice workaround!! Though I wish Mathematica had an option to set `Total `of `[]` to `Null`

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[totalWnulls]
totalWnulls[x_List] := If[MatchQ[{Null ..}] @ x, Total[x], Total[x] /. Null -> 0]

totalWnulls @ list1
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
totalWnulls @ list2
```

> ```
> 4 Null
> ```

Alternatively, define a function with two argument patterns:

```
ClearAll[totalWnulls2]
totalWnulls2[x : {Null ..}] := Total[x]
totalWnulls2[x_List] := Total[x] /. Null -> 0

totalWnulls2 @ list1
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
totalWnulls2 @ list2
```

> ```
> 4 Null
> ```

Comment: Thanks. This works, though being a beginner user at Mathematica I find this solution harder to comprehend that the one posted by Alan

Answer (score 0):

One approach (which is not completely right as pointed out in the comments ) is

```
f[list_] := (Plus @@ list) /. Null -> 0
```

Better is:

```
f[list_] := 
  If[MatchQ[list, {Null ..}], Null, Plus @@ list /. Null -> 0]
```

Null as a return value does not display on output.

Comment: sorry but I don't think this works for list2. It still returns a `0` whereas I'd like the function to return `Null` if all elements are Null

Comment: Good point.  You are right. I updated my answer.